# get error about favicon while running my website

Tags: bootstrap-4

This error occurred while trying to run my website:

> You don't have permission to access /favicon.ico

Bootstrap is included in my website, still getting this error.
I don't know why and how to resolve it. 
I am running my website on my mac laptop.

Comment: seems like a rights issue... does the system user have rights to access '/favicon.ico'

Comment: You need to configure whatever web server you are using (Apache? Nginx?) to allow access to such resource (as well as double-check the file is actually there).